# ffplay to soundflower output device

Tags: ffmpeg, core-audio

I am trying to play multiple audio streams through Soundflower 64ch and select the right channel.
The documentation is pretty well made for input devices like avfoundation but not really for output devices.

I tried to output all available devices with the command

```
ffmpeg -devices -list_devices true -i ""
```

This was the output

```
Devices:
 D. = Demuxing supported
 .E = Muxing supported
 --
 D  avfoundation    AVFoundation input device
 D  lavfi           Libavfilter virtual input device
  E sdl,sdl2        SDL2 output device
```

I also tried to output the sdl and sdl2 devices but it doesn't show anything.

```
ffmpeg -f sdl2 -list_devices 1
```

How could I get access to that device and how can I select the audio channel(s)?